# can we SQLlite fetch and combine two data on one condition which can have multiple values through user input?

Tags: python, sqlite, join

So, I am trying to combine two tables and get a output as required. Let, me share the tables first.

table1:

```
Teamname                    threeRPA    Value     Pos            
Washington Wizards (WAS)      Points    27.9      Center (C)     
San Antonio Spurs (SA)        Points    25.4      Center (C)     
Charlotte Hornets (CHA)       Points    25.3      Center (C)     
Philadelphia 76ers (PHI)      Points    24.1      Center (C)     
Detroit Pistons (DET)         Points    23.8      Center (C)     
Chicago Bulls (CHI)           Points    23.4      Center (C)     
Dallas Mavericks (DAL)        Points    23.4      Center (C)     
Washington Wizards (WAS)      Rebounds  18.0      Center (C)     
Chicago Bulls (CHI)           Rebounds  12.0      Power Forward (PF)
Portland Trail Blazers (POR)  Rebounds  11.4      Power Forward (PF)
Oklahoma City Thunder (OKC)   Rebounds  11.3      Power Forward (PF)
Washington Wizards (WAS)      Rebounds  11.3      Power Forward (PF)
Atlanta Hawks (ATL)           Rebounds  11.0      Power Forward (PF)
Denver Nuggets (DEN)          Rebounds  10.8      Power Forward (PF)
Charlotte Hornets (CHA)       Rebounds  10.8      Power Forward (PF)

table2:
Teamname                      Player              Pos                    Con            
Atlanta Hawks (ATL)           Trae Young          Point Guard (PG)                   
Atlanta Hawks (ATL)           Dejounte Murray     Shooting Guard (SG)                
Atlanta Hawks (ATL)           Saddiq Bey          Small Forward (SF)                 
Atlanta Hawks (ATL)           Jalen Johnson       Power Forward (PF)                 
Atlanta Hawks (ATL)           Clint Capela        Center (C)                         
Denver Nuggets (DEN)          Jamal Murray        Point Guard (PG)                   
Dallas Mavericks (DAL)        Derrick Jones       Power Forward (PF)                 
Denver Nuggets (DEN)          Nikola Jokic        Center (C)     
Atlanta Hawks (ATL)           Onyeka Okongwu      Center (C)                         
Washington Wizards (WAS)      Kyle Kuzma      Power Forward (PF)

So, i am taking two teams as user input suppose was and atl.
The output I want like below

Washington Wizards (WAS)      Points    27.9      Center (C)          Clint Capela,Onyeka Okongwu
Washington Wizards (WAS)      Rebounds  18.0      Center (C)          Clint Capela,Onyeka Okongwu
Atlanta Hawks (ATL)           Rebounds  11.0      Power Forward (PF)  Kyle Kuzma
```

So, its matching the `table1` values with opposition team players with that pos (position)

I am trying to do it in python/jupyter but not getting desire output.

here's my code

```
import sqlite3

# Connect to the 'NBA.db' database
conn = sqlite3.connect('NBA.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Function to fetch performance data from 'Cheatsheet' based on team name
def fetch_cheatsheet_data(team):
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Cheatsheet WHERE teamname LIKE ? OR teamname LIKE ?",
                   (f'%{team}%', f'({team})%'))
    return cursor.fetchall()

# Function to fetch players from 'teamdepth' based on team and position
def fetch_players(team, position):
    cursor.execute("SELECT playername FROM teamdepth WHERE teamname LIKE ? AND pos = ?",
                   (f'%{team}%', position))
    return [player[0] for player in cursor.fetchall()]

# User Inputs for Team Names
team1 = input("Enter Team 1 (Full name, Abbreviation, or Both): ").strip().upper()
team2 = input("Enter Team 2 (Full name, Abbreviation, or Both): ").strip().upper()

# Fetch 'Cheatsheet' Data for both teams
team1_data = fetch_cheatsheet_data(team1)
team2_data = fetch_cheatsheet_data(team2)

positions_to_fetch = ['Point Guard (PG)', 'Shooting Guard (SG)', 'Small Forward (SF)', 'Power Forward (PF)', 'Center (C)']

for position in positions_to_fetch:
    for data in team1_data:
        print(f"{data[0]} \t {data[1]} \t {data[2]} \t {data[3]}")
        opposing_team = team2 if data[0].endswith(team1) else team1
        players_opposing_team = fetch_players(opposing_team, position)
        if players_opposing_team:
            print(f"{position} Players for {opposing_team}: {', '.join(players_opposing_team)}")
        else:
            print(f"No {position} Players found for {opposing_team}")

    for data in team2_data:
        print(f"{data[0]} \t {data[1]} \t {data[2]} \t {data[3]}")
        opposing_team = team1 if data[0].endswith(team2) else team2
        players_opposing_team = fetch_players(opposing_team, position)
        if players_opposing_team:
            print(f"{position} Players for {opposing_team}: {', '.join(players_opposing_team)}")
        else:
            print(f"No {position} Players found for {opposing_team}")

# Close the connection
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# https://stackoverflow.com/q/77770315/459745

import collections
import sqlite3

Cheatsheet = collections.namedtuple("Cheatsheet", "teamname,threerpa,value,pos")
Teamdepth = collections.namedtuple("Teamdepth", "teamname,player,pos")
Output = collections.namedtuple("Output", "teamname,threerpa,value,pos,players")


def custom_row_factory(cursor: sqlite3.Cursor, row: tuple):
    field_names = tuple(x[0] for x in cursor.description)

    if field_names == Cheatsheet._fields:
        return Cheatsheet(*row)
    elif field_names == Teamdepth._fields:
        return Teamdepth(*row)
    elif len(row) == 1:
        return row[0]
    return row


def show_team(conn: sqlite3.Connection, this_team: str, opposition_team: str):
    cheat = conn.execute(
        "SELECT * FROM Cheatsheet WHERE teamname LIKE ?",
        (f"%{this_team}%",),
    )

    rows = []
    for row in cheat:
        players = conn.execute(
            "SELECT player FROM Teamdepth WHERE teamname LIKE ?" " AND pos = ?",
            (f"%{opposition_team}%", row.pos),
        ).fetchall()
        rows.append(Output(*row, ",".join(players)))

    return rows


def main():
    """Entry"""
    with sqlite3.connect("NBA.db") as conn:
        conn.row_factory = custom_row_factory

        fmt = "%-30s %-10s %6.1f %-20s %s"
        for row in show_team(conn, "WAS", "ATL"):
            print(fmt % row)
        for row in show_team(conn, "ATL", "WAS"):
            print(fmt % row)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
Washington Wizards (WAS)       Points       27.9 Center (C)           Clint Capela,Onyeka Okongwu
Washington Wizards (WAS)       Rebounds     18.0 Center (C)           Clint Capela,Onyeka Okongwu
Washington Wizards (WAS)       Rebounds     11.3 Power Forward (PF)   Jalen Johnson
Atlanta Hawks (ATL)            Rebounds     11.0 Power Forward (PF)   Kyle Kuzma
```

Notes

- I hard-coded WAS and ATL because I am lazy, please add your `input()` calls
- To aid reading and to make code clearer, I created a bunched of named tuple, along with `custom_row_factory()` in order to convert rows from tuples to these named tuples.
- `custom_row_factory()` also convert tuples with 1 element into the element itself, thus simplifying the code which select players

Comment: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'Pos' getting this error

Comment: Pay attention to the attributes in the two named tuple `Cheatsheet` and `Teamdepth`, fix them to match your database.